# Adding a GUI to Python Quiz

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hello Stackoverflow members, I come to you today in need of help with adding a tkinter GUI to my Python quiz

```html
from random import shuffle


print('Welcome to the wonderful quiz on economics!')
print('This quiz will involve simple economics questions')

qas = [
    ('Question', 'Economics'),
    ('Question', 'Economics'),
    ('Question', 'Economics'),
    ('Question', 'Economics'),
    ('Question', 'Economics'),
   
   
]
shuffle(qas)
numRight = 0
wrong = []

numQuestions = int(input("How many questions? "))

for question, rightAnswer in qas[:numQuestions]:
    answer = input(question + ' ')
    if answer.lower() == rightAnswer:
        print('Right!')
        numRight += 1
    else:
        print('No, the answer is %s' % rightAnswer)
        wrong.append(question)

print('You got %d right and the following wrong:' % (numRight))
for q in wrong:
    print(q)
```

I also have a problem with the answering the question in the Quiz, I can type the answer as 'Economics' yet it says the question was answered incorrectly.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service. Try writing the GUI, and when you get stuck on a specific problem you can come back and ask about it.

Comment: Maybe you should fix the bugs *before* trying to implement a GUI, and read [ask]?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that simple to add a GUI to any script. My advice is to use Tkinter as a GUI because it is built in. Go [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) to find out more.

Comment: It isn't that hard too.

Answer (score 0):

As for not getting the correct answer, try

`if answer.lower is rightAnswer:`

Instead of

`if answer.lower() == rightAnswer:`

To answer your question about the GUI, well it's too broad. It seems when you say "you need help", you would like one of us to teach you the API of Tkinter and how to apply it. That is not what Stack Overflow is for, so instead I will point you to Bucky's Tkinter tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBwibXFtPtflztSNPGuIB_d

EDIT: Sorry I did not realize that this post was from 2015, not 2016. Hopefully it will help anyone with future issues.